# Castle Windsor - passing Type as constructor parameter

Tags: c#, .net, castle-windsor

I have a class that takes `Type` as a constructor parameter. How can I register this in the Windsor container?

```
   public Class NLogLogger : ILogger
   {
      private NLog.Logger _logger;  
      public NLogLogger(Type type)
      {
           _logger = NLog.LogManager.GetLogger(type.FullName);
      }
    ...
   }
```

I am trying to register it this way:

```
            container.Register(Component.For(typeof(ILogger))
                                .ImplementedBy(typeof(NLogLogger))
                                .LifestyleTransient()
                                .DependsOn(new Hashtable
                                            {
                                                {"type", ???}
                                            }));
```

I need to fill in the `???`. I could not figure out how I can pass the calling class's `Type` there.

Comment: What is `the calling class's Type`? The type of the class that does `container.Resolve<ITest>()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update**

Going by your update you want to inject the type so that you can use it for logging. There are two solutions.

```cs
public class ClassDependentOnLogger
{
    private ILogger _logger;  
    public ClassDependentOnLogger(ILogger logger)
    {
        _logger = logger;
    }

    ....

}
```

1 - Use a Windsor [SubDependancyResolver](http://www.castleproject.org/container/documentation/trunk/manual/mktypedocs/Generated_ISubDependencyResolver.html). The example below shows how to return and instance of an ILog but you could easily adapt it to return a Type instead if that is what you wanted to do:

```cs
public class LoggerResolver : ISubDependencyResolver
{
    private readonly IKernel kernel;

    public LoggerResolver( IKernel kernel )
    {
        this.kernel = kernel;
    }

    public object Resolve( CreationContext context, ISubDependencyResolver contextHandlerResolver, Castle.Core.ComponentModel model, DependencyModel dependency )
    {
        return NLog.LogManager.GetLogger(model.Implementation.FullName);
    }

    public bool CanResolve( CreationContext context, ISubDependencyResolver contextHandlerResolver, Castle.Core.ComponentModel model, DependencyModel dependency )
    {
        return dependency.TargetType == typeof( ILogger );
    }
}

//Register the sub dependency resolver. This looks cleaner if you do it via a
//Facility but that's a whole other class
Container.Kernel.Resolver.AddSubResolver( new LoggerResolver( Kernel ) );
```

2 - Use the Windsor [LoggingFacility](http://www.castleproject.org/container/facilities/v1rc3/logging/index.html)

There is no need for the NLoggerClass described in your example.

Comment: @user1178376 Sorry, it's getting late and i'm making stupid mistakes. I removed one of the "important bits" when I removed logic from our specific implementation. In the sub dependency resolver you can get the type of the thing that you are creating the dependency for from the ComponentModel, updated the answer.

Comment: @bronumskiThanks, the `SubDependencyResolver` approach worked fine. `model.Implementation` in the `SubDependencyResolver` gives the `Type` information of the class for which I am creating an instance of `ILogger`. But still wondering why it would not give me the `Type` when I use it in `DependsOn` context.

Comment: Updated links to [Resolvers](https://github.com/castleproject/Windsor/blob/master/docs/resolvers.md) and [Logging Facilities](https://github.com/castleproject/Windsor/blob/master/docs/logging-facility.md).